# Getting JS error log electron from release mode

Tags: javascript, electron

I am currently working in electron, however in release mode there are bugs that are not in the dev environment. Is there a way to easily receive a log of js errors since devtools is not allowed in release versions of the app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an exception handler:

```
try {
     alert("Welcome guest!");
}
catch(err) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
}
```